# Django imageField, как добавить изображение в папку приложения и на форму?

Tags: django, изображения

Я пытаюсь добавить изображение на форму проекта и в папку, нашел мануал на английском,`https://coderwall.com/p/bz0sng/simple-django-image-upload-to-model-imagefield` но он мне не совсем не понятен, повторил все в нем указанное но результата не достиг, все время выводит "allowed only via POST", плюс не понял откуда брать картинку, содержимое моих файлов:

```
#forms.py
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.Form):
    """Image upload form."""
    image = forms.ImageField()

#models.py
from django.db import models

class ExampleModel(models.Model):
    model_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'pic_folder/', default = 'pic_folder/None/no-img.jpg')
```

```
#urls.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from firstapp import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import static
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.upload_pic),
]
```

```
#views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ImageUploadForm
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseForbidden


def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            m = ExampleModel.objects.get(pk=course_id)
            m.model_pic = form.cleaned_data['image']
            m.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
    return HttpResponseForbidden('allowed only via POST')
```

```
#upload_pic.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Django Forms</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        {{ form }}
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ну так allowed only via POST, а проверяете вы почему-то чтобы было GET. Естественно, GET это не POST, проверка не срабатывает и ничего не загружается. Ваш код отличается от кода по ссылке, в оригинале написана правильная проверка

Comment: Да да, исправил изначально было POST, GET появился уже в моих попытках

Comment: И после исправления всё равно не загружается? Значит форма невалидная, читайте `form.errors` для выяснения подробностей

Comment: Суть вопроса заключается в том что это моя первая попытка использования класса imagefield в джанго, единственный более менее подробный пример является англоязычным, и я не понимаю как указать путь к изображению

Comment: ошибок в cmd нет, как я понимаю 'allowed only via POST' это часть конструкции в случае не загрузки, но что загружать то я не указал и как я понимаю он пошел по этой ветке, где мне здесь и как указать загружаемый файл?

Comment: Ну так вы `form.errors` прочитали-то?

Comment: Нет, т.к. выполняется без ошибок.

Comment: Вы же сами написали в тексте вопроса, что у вас возникает ошибка allowed only via POST. Давайте вы не будете противоречить сами себе и прочитаете `form.errors`?

Comment: я не противоречу. как я понимаю form.is_valid() это валидация формы ```https://djbook.ru/rel1.9/ref/forms/api.html```, и так как ее выполнить невозможно по причине того что форма не заполнена, так как я и изначально писал что не понимаю как запомнить форму. Или вы хотите сказать что мануал который я использовал изначально неверен?

Comment: Она у вас замечательно заполняется из request.POST и request.FILES, когда вы отправляете заполненную форму в вашем браузере на странице, которая рисуется из шаблона upload_pic.html

Comment: Если вы вдруг не добавили никакой страницы, на которой используется шаблон upload_pic.html, то вам следует её добавить. Ну а мануал действительно ужасен, да. Чем не угодила официальная документация Django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
class ImageUploadForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """Image upload form."""
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**template**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**views**

```
def upload_pic(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ImageUploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponse('image upload success')
        else:
            response = {}
            for k in form.errors:
                response[k] = form.errors[k][0]
            return HttpResponse({"response": response})
    else:
        return render(request, 'upload_pic.html', {'form': ImageUploadForm()})
```

Comment: Зря и вы тоже не читаете `form.errors`

Comment: @andreymal только у него с другим проблемы возникли же.

Comment: Ну а потом однажды возникнут проблемы и с `form.errors` тоже. Почему бы не смотреть на шаг вперёд и не писать сразу хороший код, раз вы уж начали пытаться писать что-то похожее на хорошее?